# Missing logs - Tomcat 5.5 + Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: configuration, logging, ubuntu-8.04, tomcat5.5

**Summary**

Freshly-installed (via `apt-get`) Tomcat on a freshly-installed Ubuntu 8.04 LTS 64-bit works, but doesn't (seem to) log anything.  See also "**What I've Tried**" and "**Closing In On It**" below.

**More Detail**

Because the package maintainers have done a HUGE amount of the work, getting basic things working has been a fairly straightfoward matter of running `apt-get` and pointing Tomcat at the right JDK.  And it works.  But it doesn't appear to log anything.

As far as I can tell, the logging infrastructure is controlled via `logging.properties` files (since this is Tomcat 5.5, not Tomcat 5.0), including a central one (which you can override per web app) at `/etc/tomcat55/logging.properties` (`/etc/tomcat55` is symlinked as `/var/lib/tomcat55/conf`).  I'm not overriding it, and I can't see why I'm not seeing *something*.  Here's the file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = admin.

5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = DEBUG
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].handlers = 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = DEBUG
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = DEBUG
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = DEBUG
```

The only change I've made is:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = DEBUG
```

...which was set to `INFO` like all the others, but I wanted to get it to log *something*, so I upped it to `DEBUG`.  Naturally I've restarted Tomcat.

I can compile and view a JSP, so again Tomcat is *working*, but `/var/lib/tomcat5.5/logs` is stubbornly empty.  Even if I force an error by having an invalid JSP or some such, I'm getting nothing.

**What I've Tried**

- I've been through the steps listed in the [Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q9) for ensuring that the distro hasn't messed things up (they hadn't).
- I've gone looking for a `logs` directory elsewhere in case it's not `/var/lib/tomcat5.5/logs` (although that was created by the install).
- Naturally I've restarted Tomcat after making any changes.

One thing I *haven't* done is to `chown` everything to be owned by the `tomcat55` user that the install created.  `logs` is owned by `tomcat55`, but a number of the other directories and files are owned by `root`, though they're world-readable.  I haven't done this because (*hangs head*) I can't quite figure out how to fully back-up the existing tree so I can readily undo the change. The blasted tree has absolute symlinks interweaving `/etc/tomcat55`, `/var/lib/tomcat55`, and `/usr/share/tomcat55` *that I know of*.  I could tar up each of those, but I don't know for certain I'm not missing something.

**EDIT:**

**Closing In On It**

Okay, so I've found that it's writing console-style stuff to `/var/log/daemon.log`. Whew! At least that gives me a place to start.  And it's issuing complaints like:

```
jsvc.exec[18819]: Can't load log handler "2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
jsvc.exec[18819]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

And I'm not surprised, `2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler` isn't a valid class name (packages can't start with digits!).  So I'm suspecting that the default `logging.properties` file is...not good.  Will report back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out -- the package doesn't *quite* work right with Sun's latest Java6 package, `sun-java6-jdk`; the fix is fairly straightforward when you find it:

Once I found the `daemon.log`, I found the errors listed in my edit on the question, but those are just a side-effect of this error:

```
jsvc.exec[18819]: Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
jsvc.exec[18819]: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContextClassLoader)
```

...which occurs because the package, by default, runs Tomcat using the Java security manager per this setting in `/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5`:

```
# Use the Java security manager? (yes/no)
TOMCAT5_SECURITY=yes
```

...but the package *doesn't* set a permissions on JULI (the default logging implementation) that the latest Java6 from Sun appears to need for that to work.  Earlier versions of Java6 were apparently fine.  [This recent thread](http://www.nabble.com/webapps-examples-and-security-manager-td25563055.html) on the tomcat-user mailing list pointed me in the right direction; the user in question there was getting the error above and eventually Mark Thomas figured out that this permission:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
```

...was missing from `catalina.policy`.  And indeed, if I add that permission to the JULI section of `/etc/tomcat5.5/policy.d/03catalina.policy` and restart Tmocat, the error goes away, and I get log files!  **Huzzah**!

Be warned:  If you also install `tomcat5.5-webapps` to get the examples, manager application, etc., there are other settings you'll need to enable in `03catalina.policy`.  Of course, you always have the option of turning the security manager off, but this is what it's *for*.

Answer (score 0):

All the official bug report about that problem is here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat5.5/+bug/410379